# How does Firebase update one callable function when you modify a code used by many other functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I find myself in this situation way too often, and I can't find a clear explanation as to what is the right way to go.

Say you have (n) callable functions, (m) triggers, that all use an internal piece of code that you update.
Should you deploy all functions that use that code, or updating one of them will propagate to the others ?

PS : When I deploy the whole project, it usually fails. So now I only deploy functions individually which seems to work better.
But deploying functions one by one is very tedious.
Even when I deploy a list of functions it fails
ie : `firebase deploy --only functions:function1,function2`

Comment: Do you have any idea why deploying the entire project fails? That sounds like the bigger issue. I have never had a project fail to deploy, even with 20+ functions and hosting (not the biggest project, but still pretty big). What error do you get?

Comment: Also, what language are you using?

Comment: I use typescript, and I have over 200 functions. I find different errors in the console telling me "failed to create function path/to/fuction" in some of them, without telling me why or "Failed to configure trigger for event-type:providers/path/to/functions" and always "Error: There was an error deploying functions" at the end. But deploy one at a time works

Comment: I have found the reason why there are errors in my deployments. It's because the deploy command run `tsc` to build the project but does not clean up the previous build. As a result, if you rename files, old ones will remain in the lib folder causing issues. Solution is to add a predeployment script that removes the lib folder before the tsc command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfamiliar with the answer to your question, I ran a quick test in typescript.

```
exports.testing1 = functions.https.onCall(test1);
exports.testing2 = functions.https.onCall(test2);

export async function getString(): Promise<(String)>{
    return("Hello test");
    //return "Hello World";
}
export async function test1(){
    //console.log("New test1");
    console.log(await getString());
}
export async function test2(){
    console.log(await getString());
}
```

I added these functions, then switched out the return hello test for hello world in the helper function, and added in the commented out New test 1 print. Then I ran

```
firebase deploy --only functions:testing1
```

Then called both functions again. testing1 updated to the new output, testing2 did not.

I appears that each functions compile completely, and run in their own runtime environment, which makes sense for stability and scalability purposes. Therefore, we can conclude updating a helper function and then not updating the entire project could cause some functions to use the old helper function.

Comment: I am thinking about a work around for your situation, will update my answer if I come up with anything

Comment: Might be worth starting a seperate question with regards to the full deploy errors you are getting, as that would solve this issue, even if it takes forever to upload the entire project each time

Comment: Thank you Chris for your input ! I appreciate your efforts. In my case, every function lives in a separate file, and so do helper functions. In your example, all the changes you made live in the same file and firebase only updated the function you specified.
So that answers my question. As to why I have deploy errors, I have tried many approches, read many similar questions, but none of theme brings a solution.  I suspect it has to do with the fact my functions were deployed in container registry and now Google tries to push toward Artifact registry. But I don't know how to migrate my project

Comment: Another error I got a lot is "got "Quota Exceeded" error while trying to update function ..."